# get to an UIView frame a zoom animation

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, uianimation

I am trying to add one UIView with a transition style zoom animation like this:

```
     ^
     |
 <---.--->
     |
     v
```

The view start with a little frame (centerParent.x, centerParent.y,20, 20) and then change to (centerParent.x, centerParent.y,300, 300).

But when I change the frame I have to change it since the postion (0.0) of the view, not for it's center point. Does anyone know how to do it?

Thanks

Comment: could you plz describe your animation? the graph is difficult for us to understand.

Comment: I try to explain it better :)

Comment: Maybe you can embedded it in an UIScrollView and use the method zoomToRect:animated: to get the same effect.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With the methodology you're currently using (not using a transform but simply resizing the view) you just need to reset the origin or center of the view). The easiest is the center:

```
 view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 20, 20);
    CGPoint center = view.center;
    [UIView animateWithDuration: 1.0f animations:^{
        view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 300, 300);
        view.center = center;
    }];
```

You can also reset the origin by moving subtracting 1/2 the difference of the size change from the x and y, but this is more math:

```
view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 20, 20);
    CGPoint origin = view.frame.origin.
    [UIView animateWithDuration: 1.0f animations:^{
        origin.x -= (300 - 20) / 2;
        origin.y -= (300 - 20) / 2;
        view.frame = CGRectMake(origin.x, origin.y, 300, 300);
    }];
```

Comment: I use the second solution. No re scaling working fine! Thanks :)

Comment: @Aaron Hayman - Can you please tell me how to shrink the view with animation . Thanks in advance.

Comment: @PankajGupta You just need to use the same math as I described in the answer.  Basically, take the origin and subtract out half the difference between the new size and the old size.  Set the view frame to the new origin + size inside the animation block.

Answer (score 1):

To make a view zoom out, while keeping it's own center is easy but you need to use transform.  here is a code.
Just add and connect a view, named it zoomerView.

In this example, I just add this to the main view touches ended.

```
- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    CGPoint center = zoomerView.center;
    [UIView animateWithDuration:1 animations:^{
        zoomerView.transform = CGAffineTransformScale(zoomerView.transform, 1.2, 1.2);
    }];
}
```

Hope this helps you

Comment: Thanks by the answer but I use set frame because I need a good resolution.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:secs delay:1.0 options:option
                     animations:^{
                         yourview.transform = CGAffineTransformScale(view.transform, 100.0, 100.0);
                     }
                     completion:nil];
```

Comment: This probably would work, but the view would not constantly re-render so if the animation was even the slightest bit long, it would be very poor quality.