# Animate rectangle by change width and height

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, animation

I have `ImageView` in my `UIViewController`:

[image]

And i want to animate this Image, periodically change width and height. The same animation you can see at Apple Wallet app on Iphone, if you click "Scan code". I tried a lot, but my code working incorrect or app begin lagging after 3-5 min...

This is my last code:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var focusImage: UIImageView!
    override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
        self.resizeFocusImageUp()
    }
    func resizeFocusImageUp() {
        UIView.animateWithDuration(2.0, delay: 0.0, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.CurveEaseIn, animations: {
            self.focusImage.frame = CGRectMake(
                self.focusImage.frame.origin.x+50,
                self.focusImage.frame.origin.y-50,
                self.focusImage.frame.size.width-50,
                self.focusImage.frame.size.height+50
            )
            self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
            self.view.bringSubviewToFront(self.focusImage)
            }, completion: {(Bool) in
                self.resizeFocusImageDown()
            })
    }

    func resizeFocusImageDown() {
        UIView.animateWithDuration(2.0, delay: 0.0, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.CurveEaseOut, animations: {
            self.focusImage.frame = CGRectMake(
                self.focusImage.frame.origin.x-50,
                self.focusImage.frame.origin.y+50,
                self.focusImage.frame.size.width+50,
                self.focusImage.frame.size.height-50
            )
            self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
            self.view.bringSubviewToFront(self.focusImage)

            }, completion: {(Bool) in
                self.resizeFocusImageUp()
        })
    }

}
```

Also, for my `ImageView` i use constraints:
[image]

Comment: If you're using autolayout you should animate your constraints instead of the frame

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the other poster said, if you're using AutoLayout then you need to animate the constraints, not the frame.

Create constraints for the height & width of your view, and position if you need to move it in your animation. Then control-drag from your CONSTRAINTS into the header of your view controller to create outlets.

Then in your animation block change the constant value of each constraint, then call layoutIfNeeded to trigger the animation. (The critical part is that the call to layoutIfNeeded needs to be inside the animation block. It seems that what actually causes the constraint to change the size/position of the view(s).)

All that being said, for a line drawing like you show in your post, you'd be much better off using a CAShapeLayer and animating the path of the layer. You'd get much crisper-looking shapes, and the animations are very smooth.

Comment: but how to stop and reset animation, when view disappear and appear again.

Comment: If your add a CAShapeLayer as a sublayer of the view then when you remove the view it will remove the layer (and its animations) as well. Alternately you can send the `removeAllAnimations` message to a layer.

Answer (score 1):

//Below Objective-C code working correctly in my app. Do your stuff as per your requirements.

**Note: If you are using autoalyout for that object(Image view) then add below two line code in view did load method.**

```
  imageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = YES;
  imageView.frame = CGRectMake(x, y, width, height);

//Method For Zoom IN Animations Of View
-(void)ZoomInAnimationOfView{

       imageView.transform = CGAffineTransformScale(CGAffineTransformIdentity, 0.01, 0.01);

    [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0 animations:^{
        imageView.transform = CGAffineTransformScale(CGAffineTransformIdentity, 1.0, 1.0);
    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
        imageView.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;

    }];

}
```

//Method For Zoom Out Animations

```
-(void)ZoomOutAnimationOfView{

      imageView.transform = CGAffineTransformScale(CGAffineTransformIdentity, 1.0, 1.0);

    [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0 animations:^{
        imageView.transform = CGAffineTransformScale(CGAffineTransformIdentity, 0.001, 0.001);
    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
        imageView.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;
    }];
}
```

Comment: @Arti, also this link also follow same scenario. Pls review it:-http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11261618/get-to-an-uiview-frame-a-zoom-animation